# PHP Replace part of string when

Tags: php, replace

I have searched along time, but have not found an answer, my question is,
how to build some code that work's like this (in PHP):

```
$a = "hello my worth is 488,39€ and less"; 
$b = "€"; 
$c = var;
if($a contains $b (plus the value of numbers that's infront of $b as $c))
    delete $c from $a and SELECT * FROM table WHERE c LIKE $c AND c < $c;
```

Hope some one has an answer for my question, tried many times with regax & str_replace,

Edit:
Yes, the string could contain more numbers than '488,39€', the string could also contain a number like 1.5 or -3 and more.

What I mean with $b as $c:
$b is only the euro sign, without any number, but I want the number, and only the number that is "in one word" with the euro sign + the euro sign. And that output should be declared as value $c.

So that I can delete the number with "€" from my string and use it later for mysql.

BTW: If the $a is some like "Hello, I am 1.4 ,my worth is 488,39€ and my color is -1" should the output only  = "488,39€"

Comment: What you mean by "infront of $b as $c"?

Comment: Regex would solve it.

Comment: @hindmost, I guess he mean the actual number. In this case 488,39, since that is the value that is before "€"

Comment: Does the string **ALWAYS** ONLY contains 1 number? Or can there be several values to retrieve?

Comment: I agree with @PatrickBassut that this sounds like something you could do with a regex, but you really need to add more explanation and some examples, because your question is very unclear.

Comment: Maybe would regax do it, but when I tried, the output was always some like "3488,38€", when there was an other number like "3" infront of it

Comment: Something like this?https://regex101.com/r/vL6gO2/3

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question to be how can you extract the numeric value of the currency describing the worth of the 'speaker'.

In that case, $a is the 'statement', $b is the currency symbol and $matches is the 'worth':

```
$a = "hello my 12 worth is 488,39€ and less"; 
$b = "€"; 
preg_match("/[0-9\.\,]+(?=$b)/u",$a,$matches);
if (count($matches) === 1)
    echo "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE something < '$matches[0]'".PHP_EOL;
```

It is assumed that only one value can be handled.